# How to custom color Syncfusion BarChart column depending on value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bar-chart, syncfusion-chart

Is there a way to change the color of the column depending on the value?

Highest/Lowest columns need to have different colors to separate them from the rest of the values.

- I am using the `BarSeries` with the `syncfusion-charts` package to create my chart
- My data is flexible changes depending on user can't hardcode column color

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, what's the component you're referring to?

Comment: Not sure fully understand your question, but here i need to change the color of column with the highest value or the column with the lowest value in a bar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize the bar chart for each bar to have a different color there is the need to implement the [`BarSeries.onCreateRenderer`](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/callbacks). Take a look at the example below:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: BarHorizontal(),
    );
  }
}

/// Renders customized Column chart
class BarHorizontal extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Creates customized Column chart
  const BarHorizontal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BarHorizontal> createState() => _BarHorizontalState();
}

class _BarHorizontalState extends State<BarHorizontal> {
  _BarHorizontalState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      title: ChartTitle(text: 'PC vendor shipments - 2015 Q1'),
      primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      ),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
          labelFormat: '{value}M',
          title: AxisTitle(text: 'Shipments in million'),
          majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
          majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(size: 0)),
      series: <ChartSeries<ChartSampleData, String>>[
        BarSeries<ChartSampleData, String>(
          onCreateRenderer: (ChartSeries<ChartSampleData, String> series) =>
              _CustomColumnSeriesRenderer(),
          dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(
              isVisible: true, labelAlignment: ChartDataLabelAlignment.middle),
          dataSource: <ChartSampleData>[
            ChartSampleData(x: 'HP Inc', y: 12.54),
            ChartSampleData(x: 'Lenovo', y: 13.46),
            ChartSampleData(x: 'Dell', y: 9.18),
            ChartSampleData(x: 'Apple', y: 4.56),
            ChartSampleData(x: 'Asus', y: 5.29),
          ],
          width: 0.8,
          xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData sales, _) => sales.x as String,
          yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData sales, _) => sales.y,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _CustomColumnSeriesRenderer extends BarSeriesRenderer {
  _CustomColumnSeriesRenderer();

  @override
  BarSegment createSegment() {
    return _ColumnCustomPainter();
  }
}

class _ColumnCustomPainter extends BarSegment {
  final colorList = [
    const Color.fromRGBO(53, 92, 125, 1),
    const Color.fromRGBO(192, 108, 132, 1),
    const Color.fromRGBO(246, 114, 128, 1),
    const Color.fromRGBO(248, 177, 149, 1),
    const Color.fromRGBO(116, 180, 155, 1)
  ];

  @override
  Paint getFillPaint() {
    final Paint customerFillPaint = Paint();
    customerFillPaint.isAntiAlias = false;
    customerFillPaint.color = colorList[currentSegmentIndex!];
    customerFillPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    return customerFillPaint;
  }
}

class ChartSampleData {
  ChartSampleData({this.x, this.y});

  final dynamic x;
  final num? y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To customize the color of each bar you can use pointColorMapper property like this.

```
SfCartesianChart(
    plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
      axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
      majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(size: 0),
    ),
    primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
      axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
      isVisible: false,
      majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(size: 0),
      minorTickLines: MinorTickLines(size: 0),
    ),
    series: <CartesianSeries>[
      BarSeries<Map<String, dynamic>, String>( // Use String for x-axis values
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),

        pointColorMapper: (Map<String, dynamic> data, _) => data['color'],

        animationDuration: 300,
        dataSource: <Map<String, dynamic>>[
          {'category': '6pm', 'value': 5, 'color' : Colors.red},
          {'category': '3pm', 'value': 8.2, 'color' : Colors.green},
          {'category': '12noon', 'value': 3, 'color' : Colors.grey},
          {'category': '6am', 'value': 2, 'color' : Colors.red},
          {'category': '3am', 'value': 1, 'color' : Colors.red},
        ],
        xValueMapper: (Map<String, dynamic> data, _) => data['category'],
        yValueMapper: (Map<String, dynamic> data, _) => data['value'],
      ),
    ],
  )
```